# Span doesn't get updated within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm trying to update div span text from ajax call, here is my html structure :

```
<div id="23" class="message product error">
        <strong>
            <br> 
            <strong>Unique id Id:</strong>
            <span class="uniqueId" style="color: #000; font-weight: bold;">job_201208311928_78749</span>
            <br> 
            <strong>Job Status:</strong> 
            <span class="status" style="color: #000; font-weight: bold;">IN PROGRESS</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to update status `IN PROGRESS` to `SHIPPED`

But my jquery fails to do it :

```
function update (item){
    $('#' + item.id + "span.status").text(item.CurrentStatus);
}
```

`Item.id` and `item.CurrentStatus` both have right values when I alert.

Comment: As uncovered by the people who added tabs, you have a hanging <strong> tag.  Two things: first, unless you have a (SEO/Accessibility) reason for the strong tag, you should make every effort to leave the presentation separate from the content.  It doesn't always work, but you should try.  Second, use tabbing/indentation to catch syntax mistakes like unclosed tags, etc.  It's possible that Stack Overflow removed your tabs, but just a friendly reminder. :)

Comment: Did you find the answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a space before your span:

```
function update (item){ 
    $('#' + item.id + " span.status").text(item.CurrentStatus); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Gotta insert a space there.

```
$('#' + item.id + ' span.status').text(item.CurrentStatus);
```

Or to make it even clearer:

```
$('#' + item.id).find('span.status').text(item.CurrentStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need a space in your selector:

```
function update (item){
    $('#' + item.id + " span.status").text(item.CurrentStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a space in selector

Try this

```
 $('#' + item.id + " .status").text(item.CurrentStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you need to insert a space. This space indicates, that the `<span>` element with the class *status* is a **descendant** of the element with the given `id`.

Without the space, you're saying give me the element with the `id` `<id>span` (e.g. `23span`) with the class *status*.

```
function update (item){ 
    $('#' + item.id + " span.status").text(item.CurrentStatus); 
}
```